# Testing with "Test" and "Test File"

Tags: testing, netbeans

I'm running junit tests in Netbeans. When you choose "Test" all your test run. When you choose "Test File" the single test file selected is run. Due to application environment, some of my tests can pass only when running the single file. That's why I am wondering if there is any technique to ingore test when "Test", but run it when choosing "Test File"?

Comment: "*Due to application environment, some of my tests can pass only when running the single file*" - then your tests are wrong. You should fix that problem first.

Comment: It is not a problem. When tested feature uses a bean intiliazed when application starts, you have no choice but start the application all over again between test runs.